# Source Protection when other people changing code

Tags: php, copy-protection

How to protect source code when the code want to change by other people.

Example :

I have code like this

```
<?php include("xfiles.php"); echo "blablabla";?>
```

if my code want to change by others like remove include code, i wan't that code automatically recode with create include code like before.

how do i must to do?

Comment: how in the world are people changing your code? Sounds like you need a source control repo, like Github.

Comment: yes i have git, it's about copyright, i use obfuscator software too, like fopo.com.ar and i use PHP Application Distribution License System.